# 16.04 LTS does not boot as the sole OS

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation

I installed a new HDD on my old home-built PC (intel DG31PR board with G31 chipset + LGA775 socket + Intel Pentium D 3GHz processor, all 2009 vintage) and loaded on it Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (32bit) from USB stick as the SOLE OS.There is no other OS on the machine. 
It loaded without problem and properly rebooted upon completion. I downloaded updates and a couple of standard packages from Ubuntu store. It booted up flawlessly when I started it after 2 hours although there was considerable screen flicker which disappeared after some time. 
After a shut-down for 4 hours, it failed to boot - after the Bios screen, it turned purple briefly then went black. I could hear the processor fan going up and down, but it did not light up after that. Thinking that perhaps 16.04 is too new for an old machine, I loaded 14.04 LTS in a separate partition and post-installation it booted up OK. It even booted a short while later on giving me a choice of 14.04 or 16.04 through GRUB menu. After I let it rest overnight, it shows no sign of booting up this morning. Even my attempts to go into the BIOS menu do not succeed - it goes ahead and tries to boot, but does not. Now I am even unable to boot from the live USB stick.
Repeatedly trying to reboot it using the "reset" button bricked my two earlier HDDs (hence the new one!). 
 The machine used to dual-boot 12.04 and then 14.04 with XP for about 4 years. Problems began with 14.04. Trying to upgrade to 14.04 started problems and going to 16.04 was the last straw. In trying to fix the problems, I bricked the HDD and XP went with it as well (no discs nor product code available)

Earlier, when I cleared the BIOS using the jumper provided for the purpose, it booted once without problem but after a longish rest lasting an hour or two, the old problem reappeared. The battery on the board is NEW. Could it be that somehow some form of "memory" leaks after a long down-time? Or is there some incompatibility between 16.04 and the Board/Bios?

1. What could be the problem?.
   2.What can I do to get it to boot 16.04 or even 14.04? 
   3.Is it a system issue with the Board/Bios? How can I fix that?
2. Was updating a problem? Does it interfere with the old Bios?

My skill level is VERY BASIC - I can use the command line if instructed clearly with the code to be used.

Update on 21 Aug 2016 AM:
Situation pretty much the same except now it briefly flashes the GRUB menu before going all black. Cannot hold the GRUB menu by hitting any button. I have also noticed that this happens when the BIOS appears only very briefly on screen.
UPDATE ON 21 AUG PM:
Removing the BIOS jumper (recommended by the Board manufacturer for recovery) or (placing it in pins 2&3 for reset) and powering up did not yield the results promised on some web pages. After placing the BIOS jumper in pins 2&3 for a while, removing the battery and replacing after some time and replacing the jumper to pins 1&2 (normal setting as per board manufacturer) I was able to get into the BIOS menu while booting up. Chose BIOS  default settings in the BIOS menu and rebooted.It rebooted into Ubuntu - for now. Clearly it is an issue involving the interaction between the BIOS and the Ubuntu OS at boot time. Anyone has any idea how to tackle this? 
UPDATE ON 22 AUG PM
I think I have figured it out using logic alone: the system was not allowing me to get into Bios. When I removed my hard disc and powered up, it showed an error message stating that there is no bootable disc. Plus, when I inserted an ISO image of Ubuntu OS, most of the time it booted. This proved that the board, despite its age, is OK. The problem could have been a BIOS corruption. My removing the battery and using the CMOS jumper to "reset" it probably overcame *that* issue. But I had done that before. It meant that the corrective measures were not being stored in the BIOS. Why? I think it was because of the battery. By disconnecting the PC from the mains, I was making the world a teeniest bit greener, but I was using up the battery for time-keeping. The board's inability to remember the previous successful boot settings beyond a few minutes explains the problems I faced. Today I kept it on through the day - actually since the last successful boot-up last night and that appears to have solved the problem of the battery being unable to power the CMOS to remember the correct boot settings. I am going to go a little anti-green and keep the power on in future to ensure that I can boot up again without any issue. Thanks guys, for helping me figure it out for myself!